# React Shared Counter Increment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to achive a shared counter between components for example
I have 3 buttons

```
<Button />
<Button />
<Button />
```

and each of them has a label that will show a number when its clicked on it
when I click one of them it will start by 1 and only the one i clicked will show that number 1 and others will be 0 or no label at all then if i click other button that button wil show 2 on it
and previous one will stay at 1 and so on when i click third button it will have state of 3
which is a shared state between 3 same component instance
I am trying to achive a gallery image selection by this i will show a label selected items and their order by numbers on it how to achive it with react hooks

Comment: Have you looked at react contexts yet?

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: This doesn't necessarily require a context, it's better to only use them when required. in this instance a grouping parent component passing down callback functions would probably suffice.

Comment: @MarkCBall I am using redux for shared state but i couldn't figure out how to achive it

Comment: @JacobSmit can you provide an example please

Comment: The current clicked button will display the total clicks of all 3 buttons?

Comment: If on click you are only rendering the button that has changed, I'd guess that you are not creating a new state object each time you update your `numClicked` value. Instead of doing something like `state.object.numClicked++` you should deep copy your state then update the entire state with the new state object.

Be mindful that 

`let x = {key1:3}
x.key++
`

will not trigger a state update if you are subscribing to x

Comment: @bertdida yes exactly

Comment: Here you go: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-69m234?file=index.tsx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-69m234?file=index.tsx). This should show you roughly how you could use a Parent component to share logic between multiple child components. The buttons have been set up to toggle, and since an array of IDs is used for calculating the selection order unselecting a button will automatically handle renumbering the other selections.

Comment: @JacobSmit thank you thats exaclty what i wanted to achive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing logic between siblings can be handled via a parent component that passes callback functions to each child.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

interface AppProps { }
interface AppState {
  photos: PhotoData[];
}

type PhotoData = { id: number; name: string; }

type GalleryProps = { photos: PhotoData[] }

const Gallery : React.FunctionComponent<GalleryProps> = ({
  photos
}) => {
  // Create an array to store the unique ID of the selected "photos".
  // As items are selected they will be inserted into the array in the order
  // they were selected.
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<number[]>([]);

  // Create a function to handle the selection of a button.
  const onSelect = React.useCallback((selectedId?: number) => {
    setSelected(currentSelected => {
      // If item already in the array, remove it.
      if (currentSelected.some(id => id === selectedId)) {
        return currentSelected.filter(id => id !== selectedId);
      }

      // if item not in the array, add it.
      return [...currentSelected, selectedId ]
    });
  }, [setSelected])

  return (
    <div>
      {
        !!photos && photos.map(photo => {
          // find the selection order using index.
          const index = selected.indexOf(photo.id);

          // change index to 1 based (or undefined if not selected).
          const selectionOrder = index >= 0 ? index + 1 : undefined

          return (
            <Photo 
              key={photo.id}
              {...photo}
              onClick={onSelect}
              index={selectionOrder}
            />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

type PhotoProps = PhotoData & { index?: number; onClick: (selectedId: number) => void; }

const Photo : React.FunctionComponent<PhotoProps> = ({
  id,
  name,
  onClick,
  index
}) => {
  // Create function to handle button click.
  const onButtonClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    onClick(id)
  }, [onClick, id])

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onButtonClick}
    >
      {name} {!!index && `(Selected ${index})`}
    </button>
  );
};

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      photos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Photo 1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Photo 2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Photo 3'
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Gallery photos={this.state.photos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Runnable Version of the above.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-69m234?file=index.tsx)